# AIR for iOS, external swf (bytecode not allowed) can instances on stage be reached using instance name?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe

I need to do the following:
AIR for iOS app
Load an external SWF from network (not compiled with the main swf), and access instances positioned on the stage. Or instances positioned in a class exported for actionscript.
Do instance names count as unloadable ABC?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think instance names count as unloadable bytecode. You just can't have any AS3 in there. Once you've loaded the SWF, you should be able to getChildByName to find your instances.

Comment: I verified. It works, instance names are not interpreted as ABC.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm it is possible. After tests I verified in iOS 9 it does not trigger any error, and successfully accesses instances on stage with correct instance name and properties.